# Flexbox. Отступы

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите задать отступы у формы, не знаю, где ошибка. Также не применяется border-bottom к input.
P.S. Только начал применять flexbox, мало опыта.

```css
head,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.logo {
  padding-left: 150px;
}

.navigation {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-right: 148px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.menu li {
  padding-left: 45px;
  color: #ffffff;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0.69;
}

.form_template {
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
  height: 713px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.logo1 {
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-top: 105px;
}

.title {
  height: 70px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.text {
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  height: 61px;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 23px;
  max-width: 70%;
}

.download {
  background: none;
  margin-left: 150px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 42px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.free_trial {
  padding-left: 222px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 360px;
  height: 363px;
}

.trial {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  width: 360px;
  height: 54px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
}

.span {
  color: #ff8b38;
}

.form-inner input {
  border-bottom: 1px;
  width: 285px;
  height: 31px;
}

.form-inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 360px;
  height: 355px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>AX IT</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AXIT.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="img/Logo.png">
    </div>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Pricing</li>
        <li>Reviews</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Form -->
  <section class="form_template">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="logo1">
        <img src="img/Logo1.png">
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        MODERN AXURE TEMPLATE FOR BEAUTIFUL PROTOTYPES
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra justo commodo.
      </div>
      <button class="download">
          Download
      </button>
    </div>
    <form class="free_trial">
      <div class="form-inner">
        <p class="trial">Try Your<span class="span">&nbsp;FREE&nbsp;</span>Trial Today</p>

        <input type="text" name="1" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" name="2" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="text" name="3" placeholder="Password">
        <button class="get_started">
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </section>
  <!-- Media -->
  <section class="social_media">
    media
  </section>
  <!-- Tabs -->
  <section class="tabs">
    tabs
  </section>
  <!-- List section -->
  <section class="list_section">
    list
  </section>
  <!-- Picture section -->
  <section class="picture_section">
    picture
  </section>
  <!-- Awesome -->
  <section class="awesome">
    awesome
  </section>
  <!-- Prices -->
  <section class="prices">
    prices
  </section>
  <!-- Reviews -->
  <section class="reviews">
    reviews
  </section>
  <!-- Design-->
  <section class="design">
    design
  </section>
  <!-- Contact form-->
  <section class="contact_form">
    contact form
  </section>
  <footer class="footer">
    footer
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил `justify-content: space-around;` для отступов между input-ми. Так же вы неправильно написали свойство `border`, `border: 1px solid цвет`. Вместо solid можно вставить тип border-а, а если не задать цвет, то он будет автоматический чёрным. Надеюсь помог.

```css
head, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 72px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.logo {
    padding-left: 150px;
}

.navigation {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding-right: 148px;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.menu li {
    padding-left: 45px;
    color: #ffffff;
    list-style: none;
    opacity: 0.69;
}

.form_template {
    background-color: #9a9a9a;
    height: 713px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.inner {
 flex-direction: column;
 max-width: 50%;
}

.logo1 {
 padding-left: 150px;
 padding-top: 105px;
}

.title {
    height: 70px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding-left: 150px;
    max-width: 100%;
}


.text {
 padding-left: 150px;
 padding-bottom: 45px;
    height: 61px;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 23px;
    max-width: 70%;
}

.download {
 background: none;
 margin-left: 150px;
    width: 135px;
    height: 42px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.free_trial {
 padding-left: 222px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 360px;
    height: 363px;
}

.trial {
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 margin: 0;
 width: 360px;
    height: 54px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    justify-content: center;
}

.span {
 color: #ff8b38;
}

.form-inner input {
  border: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid red;
 width: 285px;
 height: 31px;
}

.form-inner {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
 flex-direction: column;
 width: 360px;
 height: 355px;
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>AX IT</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AXIT.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
 <!-- Header -->
 <header class="header">
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="img/Logo.png">
   </div>
   <nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
     <li>Features</li>
     <li>About</li>
     <li>Pricing</li>
     <li>Reviews</li>
     <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
 </header>
 <!-- Form -->
 <section class="form_template">
  <div class="inner">
      <div class="logo1">
       <img src="img/Logo1.png">
      </div>
   <div class="title">
    MODERN AXURE TEMPLATE
                FOR BEAUTIFUL PROTOTYPES
   </div>
   <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean
                euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus
                accumsan et viverra justo commodo.
   </div>
   <button class="download">
    Download
   </button>
  </div>
   <form class="free_trial">
    <div class="form-inner">
         <p class="trial">Try Your<span class="span">&nbsp;FREE&nbsp;</span>Trial Today</p>
      
         <input type="text" name="1" placeholder="Name">
         <input type="text" name="2" placeholder="Email">
         <input type="text" name="3" placeholder="Password">
         <button class="get_started">
   
         </button>
       </div>
   </form>
 </section>
 <!-- Media -->
 <section class="social_media">
  media
 </section>
 <!-- Tabs -->
 <section class="tabs">
  tabs
 </section>
 <!-- List section -->
 <section class="list_section">
  list
 </section>
 <!-- Picture section -->
 <section class="picture_section">
  picture
 </section>
 <!-- Awesome -->
 <section class="awesome">
  awesome
 </section>
 <!-- Prices -->
 <section class="prices">
  prices
 </section>
 <!-- Reviews -->
 <section class="reviews">
  reviews
 </section>
 <!-- Design-->
 <section class="design">
  design
 </section>
 <!-- Contact form-->
 <section class="contact_form">
  contact form
 </section>
 <footer class="footer">
  footer
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```